# A problem about algorithm of string, dp, graph or sth else

Tags: algorithm, string, graph, dynamic-programming

problem is following.

1. about "nice"

   1) "ab" is nice

   2) A is nice => "a"+A+"b" is nice

   3) A and B are nice => A+B is nice
2. about "~"

   1) "ab"~"ab"

   2) A~B => "a"+A+"b"~"a"+B+"b"

   3) A~B and C~D => A+C~B+D and A+C~D+B

now there are at most 1000 string of 'a' and 'b' forming a set S, find the biggest subset of S in which every element must be nice and none of pair (A,B) holds A~B. Output the Cardinality.

There are sth different from the problems i see before:
A+B+C+D~A+C+B+D~B+D+A+C but A+B+C+D~B+D+A+C doesn't hold.

Two difficulties for me:

1. how to check whether S1~S2
2. if i know every pair's "~", how can i find the cardinality

more detail: https://www.spoj.pl/problems/ABWORDS/

Comment: Whoever voted to close: Of course it's a real question.  It's a problem in a programming competition -- if that's not a relevant question on SO, then I don't know what is.

Comment: actually, the definition of "nice" is not the same as the original problem statement. this definition only admits even number of letters!

Comment: @lijie: "if it has as many letters a as b", so number of letters must be even.

Comment: oh ok again i am guilty of not reading properly. sigh.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>The rules for constructing a nice word imply that every nice word starts with "a" and ends with "b". Hence, there is a unique (up to sequencing - rule 3) decomposition of a nice word into nice sub-words: find all "ab"s, and then try to expand them using rule 2, and sequence them using rule 3. We can express this decomposition via a tree (n branches for repeated application of rule 3).</strike>

In the tree context, the "~" relation is simply expressing isomorphic trees, I think (where branch order does not matter).

**EDIT**: as pointed out, branch order does matter.

<strike>I'll attempt to solve the problem as stated in the original link (the 2 definitions of "nice" doesn't coincide).</strike>

First, similarity between two words X and Y, using DP.

Define `f(a, b, n)` to be the function that indicates that `X[a..a+2n-1]` is similar to `Y[b..b+2n-1]` and that both subwords are nice.

```
f(a, b, 0) = 1.
```

for n > 0,

```
f(a, b, n) = f1(a, b, n) or f2(a, b, n) or f3(a, b, n)
f1(a, b, n) = x[a] == y[b] == 'a' and x[a+2n-1] == y[b+2n-1] == 'b' and f(a+1, b+1, n-1)
f2(a, b, n) = any(1 <= k < n) f(a, b, k) and f(a+2k, b+2k, n-k)
f3(a, b, n) = any(1 <= k < n) f(a, b+2(n-k), k) and f(a+2k, b, n-k)
```

I think this is O(n^4) (urgh).

For the second part, if you represent the words as a graph with edges representing the similarity relation, you are essentially trying to find the maximum independent set, I think. If so, good luck! It is NP-hard (i.e. no known better solution than to try all 
combinations) in the general case, and I don't see any properties that make it easier in this :(

**EDITED** to make the definition of similarity automatically check niceness. It is quite easy.

**EDITED** yet again because of my stupidity.

Comment: branch order may matter: A+B+C+D~A+C+B+D~B+D+A+C but A+B+C+D~B+D+A+C doesn't hold.

Comment: Well, although we can't see the properties, that there are some people having solved the problem implies the properties exist. Thanks.

Comment: updated because my interpretation of nice was wrong. and yes it should be possible (maybe the test cases are all not too unfriendly).